# Cypher results return certain structure

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to return a certain structure. 
Here is my query:

```
MATCH (tracker:tracker { active: true }) OPTIONAL MATCH (tracker { active: true })--(timer:timer) RETURN { tracker:tracker, timers:COLLECT(timer) } as trackers
```

Here is what I am returning so far:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "columns": ["trackers"],
    "data": [{
      "row": [{
        "tracker": {
          "title": "a",
          "id": "04e3fddc-5aef-4c3a-9aeb-62a9fb15bd75",
          "active": true
        },
        "timers": []
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "errors": []
}
```

I would like the timers to be nested under the "tracker" with the tracker's properties, like this:

```
{
  "results": [{
    "columns": ["trackers"],
    "data": [{
      "row": [{
        "tracker": {
          "title": "a",
          "id": "04e3fddc-5aef-4c3a-9aeb-62a9fb15bd75",
          "active": true,
          "timers": []
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MATCH (tr:tracker {active: true}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (tr)--(ti:timer) 
WITH { 
    title: tr.title, 
    id: tr.id,
    active: tr.active,
    timers: COLLECT(ti)
} as trackers
RETURN trackers
```

Comment: I'm doing this as a workaround until there is a better solution. The reason I don't want to do this is that I don't want to keep track of all the properties. Title, id, and active is what I have now, but in the future there will be many more properties and I don't want to update my query every time a new property is added.